# How add scroll view with page control when device rotate to left or right?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am designing an application in which i have a table view controller. Now I want that when I rotate device then instead of table view a scroll with page control will appear. So that I can  scroll image with page control.

And when I again rotate to portrait mode then it will so again table view.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
// Return YES for supported orientations
  if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=TRUE;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=TRUE;


  }
  else{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=FALSE;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=FALSE;
    self.tableView.hidden=FALSE;

  }

  return YES;
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation to detect when the screen rotates, then add your code to add/show/remove/hide/whatever your views based on the current orientation.

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    switch (self.interfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            //Do stuff
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

self.interfaceOrientation gives the current orientation, (portrait, upsidedown, landscapeleft, landscaperight), and you also have access to the previous orientation if you need it.